# Reading an entire row from a .xls/.xlsx file with c#

Tags: c#, excel, interop

Im trying to read a .xls/.xlsx  file using a c# program I am using excel interop. However I can only read 1 cell at a time. Can someone show me how to read an entire row and put it inside a string?

This is my code so far:

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();

                Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Path.GetFullPath("C:\\..\\A1.xlsx"));

                Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets.get_Item(1);

                Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
string temp = (string)(xlRange.Cells[1,2] as Excel.Range).Value2;
              Console.WriteLine(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have written so far is perfect. Just try and execute the temp in loop and get values for each cells as below

```
for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= xlRange.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
            {
                for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= xlRange.Columns.Count; cCnt++)
                {
                    string temp = (string)(xlRange.Cells[rCnt,Ccnt] as Excel.Range).Value2;
                    Console.WriteLine(temp);
                }
            }
```

I guess this will solve your purpose, of getting individual cells and stroing it in the string

For reading entire rows you can keep the row value constant and iterate the columns and store it in an array.